# what wrong with this hql query, I use fetch in my hql to overload the child sets

Tags: nhibernate, hql, fetch

```
 string hql = "from Customer as c left outer join fetch c.Orders" 
 + "where c.CustomerId=:id";

 using(Session)
 {
    return  Session.CreateQuery(hql).SetInt32("id",id).List<Customer>();
 }
```

when I excute the code, there is an exception like this:

> EagerLoadCustomerByIdThroughFetchTest :
>   FailedNHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException :
>   引发类型为“Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTokenException”的异常。 near line 1, column
>   56 在 NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException() 在
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse() 在
>   NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String
>   queryString, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2
>   filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) 在
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String
>   hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2
>   enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) 在
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, String
>   collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters,
>   ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) 在
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, Boolean
>   shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor
>   factory) 在
>   NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(String
>   queryString, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) 在
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(String query,
>   Boolean shallow) 在
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString) 在
>   Data.NhibernateSample.EagerLoadCustomerByIdThroughFetch(Int32 id) 位置
>   DelayLoadTest.cs: line 80 在
>   NhibernateDataAcessTest.NhibernateSampleFixture.EagerLoadCustomerByIdThroughFetchTest()
>   位置 LazyLoad.cs: line 73

what is wrong in my code ,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You SQL is malformed, there is no space between: "...c.Orders" + "where...".

Comment: I am thankful for your answer.I modified my code ,then the exception is gone,the test is success,thanks for your help